# Как обратиться к коэффициенту линейной регрессии К (у=Кх+в) в OLS Regression Results

Tags: регрессия

Каким образом вывести через print() коэффициент К (угол наклона прямой из уравнения линейной регрессии)  из таблички  OLS Regression Results? Он находится в середине всей таблицы напротив 200 и равен 0.3522.

статистика рассчитывается по данным таблицы, в которой 1000 столбцов и имена столбцов, соответственно, называются с 1 до 1000.
в def вводятся числа-имена колонок.

```
def abl_(x, y):
x = abl[x]
y = abl[y]
x = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
print(model.params)
R = model.rsquared.round(2) ** 0.5
print('coefficient of determination, R^2:', model.rsquared.round(2))
print('coefficient of correlationn, R:', R.round(2))
print('value of intersection, b:', model.params.const.round(1))
print('k-parametr:', model.params['x']) ### ТАКОЙ ВЫЗОВ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
```

[image: статистика из OLS Regression Results]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Альтернатива заданного мною вопросу такая: как вывести (напечатать через print) уравнение регрессии для двух рандомных рядов данных?